# PostgreSQL - start a server but the port is taken

Tags: postgresql

I'm on Windows and with PostgreSQL 14, I tried to make a new PostgreSQL database cluster with `initdb --locale=en_US.utf8 PGDATA`

Then I created a new PostgreSQL database with `createdb my_database`

Then I launched the server with `pg_ctl -D PGDATA -l serverlog start`

But then I get those errors:

> 2022-09-16 14:27:22.668 CEST [18596] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5,
> compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
>
> 2022-09-16 14:27:22.676 CEST [18596] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Permission denied
>
> 2022-09-16 14:27:22.676 CEST [18596] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address
> "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
>
> 2022-09-16 14:27:22.676 CEST [18596]
> WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
> 2022-09-16 14:27:22.676 CEST [18596] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
>
> 2022-09-16 14:27:22.678 CEST [18596] LOG:  database system is shut
> down

I have been told that my PORT are already used (which mean some of my applications?), so I close useless app that was starting when my computer started like "CCXProcess.exe" which related to Adobe.

I opened pgAdmin4 to look for the port used by the database there (I've just began PostgreSQL, so I only made a database in "Servers" cluster and two others empty clusters) which is 5432 (port by default)?

I then I opened a Ternimal and did `netstat -na | find "5432"` to look at the port 5432

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>
> TCP    0.0.0.0:5432          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
>
> TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING

And killed it with `taskkill /pid 5432 /f` but I got this message "5432" not founded.

I don't understand everything, so I'm probably not doing the right step. Any advice please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to kill the process with PID 5432, but `5432` is the port you were investigating right ?

The PID should be at the far right of the output of `netstat` I think

Rather try:

```
netstat -aon | findstr 5432
```

which should output something like

```
TCP    [::]:5432[::]:0                 LISTENING       18996
```

And do `taskkill /pid 18996 /f` with the correct number instead of `18996`

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work, how did you find 18996?

Comment: This is the output of the `netstat` command (at the far right of the output line)

Comment: it's strange, I don't have anything at the far right, next to "LISTENING"

Comment: Are you admin on your machine ? If not, you might not have the privilege to see the PID of this process. Also, why don't you just change the PID of the server (you should be able to change it somewhere) ?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I was already using the terminal as an admin and I use again "netstat -aon | findstr 5432" and it did show the output (the PID at the far right) which showed pid 4416 and then I could killed it with "taskkill /pid 4416 /f"